# Docker mongo sharding

Tags: mongodb, docker, sharding

I'm trying to create mongo sharding using [docker](/questions/tagged/docker). I have:

Config server:

```
docker run -it --rm --net=xnet -p 27016:27016 \
    --hostname xmongo-config-1 --name xmongo-config-1 \
    -v $PWD/docker/.data/xmongo-config-1:/data/db \
    mongo:latest --port 27016 --replSet xmongo-config --configsvr
```

And `mongos` (router) server:

```
docker run -it --rm --net=xnet -p 27015:27015 \
    --hostname xmongo-mongos --name xmongo-mongos \
    -v $PWD/docker/.data/xmongo-mongos:/data/db \
    mongo:latest mongos --port 27015 --configdb configserver/xmongo-config-1:27016
```

Now when I run:

```
docker exec -it xmongo-config-1 mongo --port 27016 --eval 'db.version()'
```

I see result `MongoDB server version: 3.4.9`

But when I run:

```
docker exec -it xmongo-mongos mongo --port 27015 --eval 'db.version()'
```

I see:

```
MongoDB shell version v3.4.9
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27015/
2018-02-16T05:54:26.434+0000 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27015, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: Connection refused
2018-02-16T05:54:26.434+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27015, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:237:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

Comment: Please add the output of docker ps also to your question

Answer (score 2):

**Mistake #1**

I've found this error in `mongos` log:

```
[mongosMain] No primary detected for set configserver
```

It means I have to init primary for my config replica set, hence run this:

```
docker exec -it xmongo-config-1 mongo --port 27016 --eval '
    rs.initiate({ _id: "xmongo-config", members: [
        { _id : 0, host : "xmongo-config-1:27016" }
    ]});
'
```

**Mistake #2**

In line for init `mongos` replace

```
--configdb configserver/xmongo-config-1:27016
```

to

```
--configdb xmongo-config/xmongo-config-1:27016
```

**Result**

It works!)